# Z3 if-then-else usage

Tags: c++, z3

I'm trying to use if-then-else to say that (pseudocode):

```
if (expression)  is true then
    (my_bool_var || true) //set variable to true
else
    (my_bool_var || false) //set variable to false
```

But Z3 goes and evaluates expression in the if statement (which is good) but the problem is that if the expression is evaluated to `false` then it turns the problem as `UNSAT` and terminates which is not my intention.

Actual code (c++ API):

```
s.add(ite(expression, my_bool_var || true, my_bool_var && false), "assertion1");
```

I just want to print the boolean variable whether it's true or false which can be done but only if the expression is true, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why not just s.add(bool_var == expression) ?

Comment: @NikolajBjorner that would automatically make the solver to return `unsat` but I want to use the result for a second expression that can be in the form of `if (my_bool_var == false && i > 20) then my_sat = true else my_sat = false` . But, because the expression gets a false value because of the previous expression, the solver stops.